# Como coloco os vários gráficos em um só

Tags: python

Basicamente preciso que ele junte os 4 gráficos que está a fazer num só, i.e. 4 linhas de cores diferentes, no mesmo gráfico para cada valor de n. O problema é que acho que a função da pressão está juntando todos os dados ao molho e não consigo chamá-los separadamente para fazer o gráfico. Alguma ajuda?

```py
n=[4,10,30,100]

for j in range(len(n)):
    Vol = 10**7 #l

    Q = 10**4 #l/min

    p0 = 1 #bar

    pf = 0.01 #bar
    
    k = 1.4

    operation_time = - np.log(pf/p0) * Vol/Q

    dt = operation_time/n[j]


    pressure_decay_imp = np.zeros(n[j]+1)

    time = np.zeros(n[j]+1)

    #initial value

    pressure_decay_imp[0] = p0

    for i in range (n[j]):
    
        dt = operation_time/n[j]
    
        pressure_decay_imp[i+1] = pressure_decay_imp[i] / (1+ dt * k*Q/Vol)
   
        time[i+1] = time[i] + dt

        print(pressure_decay_imp)
#ploting
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
    plt.plot(time,pressure_decay_imp, color = 'red')
    plt.plot(time,pressure_decay_imp, color = 'blue')
    plt.plot(time,pressure_decay_imp, color = 'green')
    plt.plot(time,pressure_decay_imp, color = 'purple')
    plt.legend(frameon=False, fontsize=10)
    plt.title("Evolução da pressão", loc="right", fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel("tempo (dias")
    plt.ylabel("pressão (bar)")

    #plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma ideia seria criar uma lista com as cores que você quer utilizar e colocar, e dentro do seu ultimo for colocar o plt.plot. Seu gráfico só vai ser plotado ao final de todas as iterações.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n=[4,10,30,100]
colors = ['red','blue','green','purple']

for j in range(len(n)):
    
    Vol = 10**7 #l
    Q = 10**4   #l/min
    p0 = 1      #bar
    pf = 0.01   #bar
    k = 1.4
    operation_time = - np.log(pf/p0) * Vol/Q
    dt = operation_time/n[j]
    pressure_decay_imp = np.zeros(n[j]+1)
    time = np.zeros(n[j]+1)

    #initial value
    pressure_decay_imp[0] = p0

    for i in range(n[j]):

        dt = operation_time/n[j]
        pressure_decay_imp[i+1] = pressure_decay_imp[i] / (1+ dt * k*Q/Vol)
        time[i+1] = time[i] + dt  
        plt.plot(time, pressure_decay_imp, color=colors[j])
          
plt.title("Evolução da pressão", loc="center", fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("tempo (dias)")
plt.ylabel("pressão (bar)")
      
plt.show()
```